# How can I verify the numbers were entered into the field in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I would like to verify numbers were entered into the field `(Selenium WebDriver)`.
What is the clearest way to do that?

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();    
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://website.com");    
driver.FindElement(By.Id("twotabsearchtextbox")).SendKeys("12345");
```

Comment: You want to write a test to test your test? If you're not confident that your test does what it's supposed to, then it's valueless and you should throw away your test. To be confident that selenium is doing what it says it's doing: watch it do its job once.  Then trust it.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
string number = driver.FindElement(By.Id("twotabsearchtextbox")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Using Selenium's `GetAttribute` to test that Selenium's `SendKeys` is working is not going to work. If Selenium is lying and reporting success from `SendKeys`, what's to stop it from lying and report "12345" from `GetAttribute`? You can't use the watchers to watch the watchers.

Comment: @PaulHicks Some textboxes have validators. Sometimes the value is reset when you enter wrong format. Take a look at datetime picker at: [expedia](https://www.expedia.com)

Comment: But wouldn't you use a js unit testing tool for that, like jasmine? Why test that through a browser?